# invalid operator '$addToSet'

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm, php-mongodb

i have one problem. When i try to execute this query, query give me this error **"invalid operator '$addToSet'"**.

```
        $qb = $this->createAggregationBuilder();
        $qb
            ->match()
            ->field('categories')->in($categories)
            ->field('hidden')->field('hidden')->notEqual(true)
            ->unwind('$type')
            ->unwind('$variants')
            ->unwind('$variants.subvariants')
            ->unwind('$variants.subvariants.params')
            ->group()
            ->field('id')->expression('$type')
            ->field('param')->addToSet(
                $qb
                    ->expr()
                    ->field('id')->expression('$variants.subvariants.params.param')
                    ->field('values')->addToSet('$variants.subvariants.params.value')
            );

        $res_params = $qb->execute()->toArray();
```

Does anyone know how to execute this query correctly?

I need result like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$ref": "Type",
            "$id": "f564ece4fe4b4cdd9f1ccd8f092a98f9",
            "$db": "skibike"
        },
        "param": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$ref": "Param",
                    "$id": "10f67225cfbe4c0e962828f32ea0fc25",
                    "$db": "skibike"
                },
                'values': [1, 2, 3]
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$ref": "Param",
                    "$id": "5ee15b7cc9404ceab9eb41f48e8622f5",
                    "$db": "skibike"
                },
                'values': [5, 4]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: What do you mean? Which documentation?

Comment: The documentation for the operations you are using like addtoset.

Comment: This.

**The addToSet strategy uses MongoDB's $addToSet operator to insert elements into the array. This strategy is useful for ensuring that duplicate values will not be inserted into the collection. Like the pushAll strategy, elements are inserted in a separate query after removing deleted elements.**

[link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.1/reference/storage-strategies.html)